# What does #self.included(base) do in Ruby on Rails' Restful Authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

I thought we would do

```
helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?, :authorized?
```

to make these controller methods available for use as helper methods in views. But in Restful Authentication's `lib/authenticated_system.rb`, I see:

```
# Inclusion hook to make #current_user and #logged_in?
# available as ActionView helper methods.
def self.included(base)
  base.send :helper_method, :current_user, :logged_in?, :authorized? if base.respond_to? :helper_method
end
```

Why is it done this way instead of that single line? Also, I don't see `included` being called anywhere.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The `self.included` function is called when the module is included. It allows methods to be executed in the context of the base (where the module is included).

More info: [a ruby mixin tutorial](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/15/mixins-in-ruby/).

Answer (score 25):

Out of the same reason which Peter has mentioned I would like to add an example so that it's easy for the newbie developers to understand *self.included(base)* and *self.extended(base)* :

```rb
module Module1
  def fun1
    puts 'fun1 from Module1'
  end

  def self.included(_base)
    def fun2
      puts 'fun2 from Module1'
    end
  end

  def self.extended(_base)
    def fun3
      puts 'fun3 from Module1'
    end
  end
end

module Module2
  def foo
    puts 'foo from Module2'
  end

  def self.extended(_base)
    def bar
      puts 'bar from Module2'
    end
  end
end

class Test
  include Module1
  extend Module2
  def abc
    puts 'abc form Test'
  end
end

class Test2
  extend Module1
end
```

```rb
Test.new.abc  #=> abc form Test
Test.new.fun1 #=> fun1 from Module1
Test.new.fun2 #=> fun2 from Module1
Test.foo #=> foo from Module2
Test.bar #=> bar from Module2
Test.new.fun3 #=> **NoMethodError** (undefined method `fun3' ..)
*Test2*.fun3 #=> fun3 from Module1
```

- extend : methods will be accessible as class methods
- include : methods will be available as instance methods
- "*base*" in self.extended(*base*) / self.included(*base*) :
  The base parameter in the static extended method will be either an
  instance object or class object of the class that extended the module
  depending whether you extend a object or class, respectively.

  When a class includes a module the module’s self.included method will
  be invoked. The base parameter will be a class object for the class
  that includes the module.

Comment: Nice explanation @FaaduBalak made my day

Comment: Hi @FaaduBaalak, can you please tell in short about 'instance object or class object', I'm little bit confused about the class object. Isn't class object mean instance of the class or isn't both same. If not then whats the difference? Thank you.

Comment: @codemilan sorry I saw this today. Were you able to find out the difference ?

Comment: Thanks @FaaduBaalak for your answer. But what is the difference between `fun1` and `fun2` - the latter is defined within `self.included(base)` while the former is not. clarity would be much appreciated.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Have added 2 more examples at the last for more clarity. Thanks

Comment: I do not know what (if anything) changed but in Ruby 2.7.0 `Test.new.fun3` runs just fine: `#=> fun3 from Module1`

Comment: i posted the question in a new thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61669750/ruby-self-extended-gets-called-as-instance-method

basically you need to add def base.fun3

Answer (score 12):

When the `AuthenticatedSystem` method is included using the `include` method, the `self.included` method is triggered with whatever it was included into being the argument of `base`.

The code you've shown calls `helper_method` and defines some helpful helpers, but only if the `base` has a `helper_method` method.

It's done that way so including the module can set up the helper methods as well as adding additional methods to the class.

Answer (score 8):

As it is the first result when searching Google for "self.included(base)" I will try to give a small example on how it works. I don't know how much it differs from the restful-authentication-approach.

It is basically used to make methods from one module available in another module.

```
module One
  def hello
    puts 'hello from module One'
  end
end

module Two
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      include One
    end
  end
end

class ExampleClass
  include Two
end

ExampleClass.new.hello # => hello from module One
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but one can simply add the line: `include One` within module `Two` and the result would be the same, wouldn't it? What is the benefit of doing it via the `self.included(base)` approach?

Answer (score 1):

Want to digger into `self.included` and `self.extended` ?

Please look at here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Module.html#method-i-included